# Output an image with PHP and Codeigniter cause the browser to show only blank screen

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to output an image to the browser via the header but the browser shows only blank black screen.

Here's my code

```
$address = FCPATH.'assets\downloaded_voucher\logo.png';
$im = imagecreatefrompng($address);

header('Content-Type: image/png');

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Result : https://prnt.sc/qbxa3i

The image file is actually exists.

I removed the header then it shows di binary of the image like this http://prntscr.com/qbxc9i

But If I use the header code it only shows blank page.

Any Solution?

Comment: Check documentation please - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php

Comment: Yes I did, but I didn't find any solution for my case

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$address = FCPATH.'assets/downloaded_voucher/logo.png';

$im = imagecreatefrompng($address);

header('Content-Type: image/png');

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: I've tried but the result is still the same. and by the way I use windows for my environment